# Having Trouble scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape automatetheboringstuff.com and output all of the practice projects and store them into a file. Eventually I want my code to move from one page to the next searching for practice projects, but right now im just trying to get beautifulsoup to pull output the practice projects on one page. It is not working though. i just get a blank [].

here's my code so far.

```
def pageDownload(webPage):
    # Downloads the page

    while not url.endswith('appendixc'):
        print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

        return soup

def getProjects(downloadedPage):
    # gets the projects contents

    soup = downloadedPage
    book =  soup.find_all('p', attrs={'title' : 'Practice Projects'})
    print(book)
```

Comment: On what page are you seeing a `p` block with a `title` set to `Practice Projects`?  (I didn't see any at first glance on the site)

Comment: Also, you have a return within a while block - is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
def pageDownload(webPage):
    # Downloads the page

    while not url.endswith('appendixc'):
        print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

        return soup

def getProjects(downloadedPage):
    # gets the projects contents

    soup = downloadedPage
    book =  soup.find_all('div', {'class': "book", 'title' : 'Practice Projects'})
    print(book)
```